# Pickle only picking up some of the list

Tags: python, pickle

If I have a list of seven items with similar names, it will only populate six of them in the pickle file. Six seems to be where the issues start, but if I move that up to nine items, it will show eight.

In the code, it does not show them under the full iteration of data2 in function access_passwords. But they will pull accurately under function access_one_pw. So they're populating, but the iteration that should be printing the device + the password does not seem to be working correctly.

```py
def add_passwords():
    data = []
    newdata = []
    pw_file_r = open('K:\\Downloads\\Chrome Downloads\\pickle.txt', 'rb')  # modify to local folder and create
    # pickle.txt document
    while True:
        try:
            data.append(pickle.load(pw_file_r))
        except EOFError:
            break
    pw_file_r.close()


    pwordN = int(input('Enter the number of devices to name: '))
    for i in range(pwordN):
        raw = input('Enter device name ' + str(i) + ' : ')
        newdata.append(raw)

    for x in newdata:
        global keyvar
        data.append(x)
        pw_file_w = open('K:\\Downloads\\Chrome Downloads\\pickle.txt', 'ab')  # modify to local folder
        pickle.dump(x, pw_file_w)
        pw_file_r.close()
        newpass = getpass.win_getpass(prompt='Enter the password for the device ' + x + ': ', stream=None)
        newpass_to_bytes = bytes(newpass, 'utf-8')
        key = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(bytes(keyvar, 'utf-8'))
        cipher_suite = Fernet(key)
        ciphered_text = cipher_suite.encrypt(newpass_to_bytes)
        db_update = shelve.open('K:\\Downloads\\Chrome Downloads\\device_shelf.db')  # modify to local folder
        try:
            db_update[x] = ciphered_text
        finally:
            db_update.close()


def access_passwords():
    data2 = []
    data2.clear()
    global keyvar
    pw_file_r = open('K:\\Downloads\\Chrome Downloads\\pickle.txt', 'rb')  # modify to local folder
    while 1:
        try:
            data2.append(pickle.load(pw_file_r))
        except EOFError:
            break
    pw_file_r.close()
    for x1 in data2:
        db_read = shelve.open('K:\\Downloads\\Chrome Downloads\\device_shelf.db')  # modify to local folder
        try:
            device = db_read[x1]
        finally:
            db_read.close()
        key = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(bytes(keyvar, 'utf-8'))
        cipher_suite = Fernet(key)
        ciphered_text = device
        unciphered_text = (cipher_suite.decrypt(ciphered_text))
        plaintxt = bytes(unciphered_text).decode("utf-8")
        print('The device ' + x1 + ' has a password of ' + plaintxt)
    restart = input('Do you want to restart the program? [Yes/No]: ')
    if restart == 'Yes':
        frun()
    else:
        pass
```

Comment: In the case that anybody has an issue like this again, I haven't been able to solve it, but I think I know where the issue is coming from at least.

Pickle is not fully populating the pickle file until the program has fully ended. Once it has ended and been reinitialized, the database shows the full list and the pickle document shows every entry from the list. 

It seems like an issue with the module coding as opposed to programmatic logic. 

Thanks.